# Draw the composition of directed graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a directed graph representing a relation $S$ on a finite set $F$. How do I draw the directed graphs representing the relation $S^2$, $S^3$, $\ldots$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ has an arrow from $a$ to $b$ and another arrow from $b$ to $c$, then $S^2$ has an arrow from $a$ to $c$.  If $S$ has an arrow from $a$ to $b$ and another arrow from $b$ to $c$ and yet another from $c$ to $d$, then $S^3$ has an arrow from $a$ to $d$.

(Somehow it seems as if, if that's not clear, you might be better off asking what the expressions $S^2$ and $S^3$ mean.)